# Authenticate dotnetnuke from WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-membership, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I have a DNN site that has all the users info. 
Currently we are planning to create a Winform Application that login with the DNN credentials through a WCF web service. But, I don't get how the WCF service can verify the username and password with DNN. I have searched a lot but of no use. Can anybody please give me a clue how to do it ?

Comment: The WCF service will need to connect with the user store (most likely a database) to validate the credentials.  Alternatively, you may be able to use validation methods if you're using some sort of membership provider.

Comment: asp.net membership works well,,, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I have done it using ASP.Net Membership. Used the same machine key as DOtnetnuke, and I could authenticate now. Thanks :)